# Is possible to execute a query on kiwi-tcms tables?

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I need to access to the test cases information and use that in a different format so I can backup in sharepoint as a plain file i.e. so, I wanna be able to extract some data like test cases or plans via query or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

> Is possible to execute a query on kiwi-tcms tables

Obviously yes. It's a database so you connect to it and run your SQL queries as you wish.

For full backups see the official method at:
https://kiwitcms.org/blog/atodorov/2018/07/30/how-to-backup-docker-volumes-for-kiwi-tcms/

For a more granular access you can use the existing API interface. See
https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/index.html and in particular https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/tcms.rpc.api.html

For an even more granular/flexible access you can interact with the ORM models directly. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#shell, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/ and https://github.com/kiwitcms/api-scripts/blob/master/perf-script-orm for examples. Kiwi TCMS database schema is documented at https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/db.html.